# How to recover redis data from snapshot(rdb file) copied from another machine?

Tags: redis, snapshot

I transferred my redis snapshot (`dump.rdb` file) using `scp` to a remote server. I need to run a redis server on this remote and recover the data from the `dump.rdb` file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 81):

For databases where the `appendonly` flag is set to `no`, you can do the following:

1. Stop Redis (because Redis overwrites the current rdb file when it exits).
2. Copy your backup rdb file to the Redis working directory (this is the `dir` option in your Redis config). Also, make sure your backup filename matches the `dbfilename` config option.
3. Start Redis.

If, on the other hand, you need to restore an rdb file to the appendonly database, you should do something along the lines of:

1. Stop Redis (because Redis overwrites the current rdb file when it exits).
2. Copy your backup rdb file to the Redis working directory (this is the `dir` option in your Redis config). Also, make sure your backup filename matches the `dbfilename` config option.
3. Change the Redis config `appendonly` flag to `no` (otherwise Redis will ignore your rdb file when it starts).
4. Start Redis.
5. Run `redis-cli BGREWRITEAOF` to create a new appendonly file.
6. Restore the Redis config `appendonly` flag to `yes`.

Specifically, this is the relevant bit of documentation from the Redis config file comments:

```
# Note that you can have both the async dumps and the append only file if you                                                     
# like (you have to comment the "save" statements above to disable the dumps).                                                    
# >> Still if appendonly mode is enabled Redis will load the data from the                                                          
# >> log file at startup ignoring the dump.rdb file.
```

Comment: and dont forget the `chown redis:redis dump.rdb` and `chmod 644 dump.rdb` after copying the files

Comment: Thanks! For me it was the `appendonly` flag set to `yes` that was causing the RDB file to be ignored and rewritten.

Comment: Thanks! After that you might still see empty result for "KEYS" in case of a large rdb file. Give it a few minutes.

Answer (score 72):

There is nothing specific to do. Just install the redis server on the new machine, and edit the configuration file. You just need to change the following parameters to point to the location of the dump file you have just copied.

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename mydump.rdb

# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
# 
# Also the Append Only File will be created inside this directory.
# 
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir /data/mydirectory/
```

Finally, the redis server can be started in the normal way.

Comment: My dump was rewrited (100Mb -> 0Mb) after I edited configuration file and restarted redis-server. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @Evgeny I think maybe you made the same mistake I did and tried to restart the server. Make sure to STOP redis first, copy the dump.rdb file to the right directory then START the server. If you restart, redis will write to the file, overwriting your copied dump, and then imports the file it wrote to instead of the file you moved as the backup.

Comment: We are successfully able to migrate db only when we first stopped redis server.

Comment: I think @Ligemer comment is pretty important! Would be nice to have it in the answer (which is spot on beside that little thing)

Comment: This is an extremely poor and dangerous answer without mentioning anything about the `appendonly` setting in the `redis.conf` file. Anytime you want to restore a redis `dump.rdb` files, you have to ensure that `appendonly` is set to `no` inside `redis.conf`. Otherwise, it will completely empty out your `dump.rdb` file and start fresh from point 0 as if nothing happened. Before careful folks!

Answer (score 27):

Assuming that you run Redis 2.6 or higher, your Redis snapshot filename is `dump.rdb`, and it exists in the directory `/home/user/dbs`, the following command would do the trick:

```
redis-server --dbfilename dump.rdb --dir /home/user/dbs
```

Relevant section from the official documentation: [Passing arguments via the command line](https://redis.io/topics/config#passing-arguments-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 14):

Or you can:

1. Stop your redis server / instance, eg.,  `service redis6379 stop`
2. Copy the dump.rdb file to the right location, eg., `cp /path/to/dump-6379.rdb /var/lib/redis/dump-6379.rdb`. Give it the right permissions (user:group should be redis:redis and mode 644)
3. Start your redis server / instance, eg., `service redis6379 start`

It is important that you stop the redis server before copying the file to the right location, because Redis saves a snapshot before terminating, so it will replace your file.

Besides, you might want to back up the existing dump.rdb file first.

Answer (score 8):

This solution work with redis-cluster, but should work too with redis.

Install this dependencie https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools

```
pip install rdbtools python-lzf
```

after that execute this

```
rdb -c protocol /path/to/dump.rdb | redis-cli -h host -p port --pipe
```

If this is a cluster, the port should the master`s port.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add here a tiny detail that did not get mentioned and I will not use config file but instead specify everything in the command line.

When both mydump.rdb and appendonly.aof files are specified when starting `redis-server`, it will be the `appendonly.aof` file that wins such that the data from appendonly.aof gets loaded. For example:

```
redis-server --dbfilename mydump001.rdb --dir /data --appendonly yes
```

The above start invocation will use the `/dir` location to find the presence of `mydump001.rdb` or `appendonly.aof` files. In this case, `redis-server` will load the contents from `appendonly.aof`. If `appendonly.aof` does not exists, it will create an empty `/data/appendonly.aof` and the redis-server will be empty.

If you want to load a specific dump file, you can do:

```
redis-server --dbfilename mydump001.rdb --dir /data
```

I added this answer coz it is not obvious which is which. In the presence of 2 backup files, and this is often not mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

start *redis* on your second server, like so:

```
$ > redis-server /path/to/my/redis/configuration/file/redis.conf
```

when redis starts, it will find your *rdb* file because it will look for the *name* 
and *file path* in the ***configuration file*** (*redis.conf*) that you supply when 
start the redis server, as above.

to supply the file name and path, just edit *two lines* in the *redis.conf* file template (supplied in the root directory of the redis source. Save your revised version as redis.conf in the directory location that you supplied upon starting the server.

You will find the settings you need in the ***redis.conf*** template in the source top-level directory, at lines *127* and *137* (redis version 2.6.9).

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb

# The working directory
dir ./
```

as you can see, defaults are provided for both settings

so just change the first of these two lines (127) to identify your rdb file 
and in the second (137) substitute the default "./" for the actual file path
for your snapshot rdb file; save the *redis.conf* with your changes, and start redis passing in this new conf file.

Answer (score 3):

Install https://github.com/leonchen83/redis-rdb-cli

```
rmt -s ./your-dump.rdb -m redis://host:port -r
```

Answer (score 2):

try set appendonly no. 
In My case, *.aof file was empty(0 byte), must set appendonly=no then make it load the dump.rdb